# Asp.NetCore - How To return tuple list from two tables?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have two tables, I want to return the value of the first table and the name of the table,Tables are related,I used the following code but it has an error?

```
public async Task<Tuple<Guid,string>> GetProductionsHorse()
{         
    return  await _context.Horses.Include(h => h.Production)
                          .Where(h => !h.IsRemove && h.IsAccept == 1)
                          .Select(p => new Tuple<Guid,string>(p.ProductionId, p.Production.Title))
                          .ToListAsync();
}
```

[image]

Can I access both values ​​if I return the value?

Comment: Yes, why do you ask? Did you encounter a specific problem? Are you looking for an alternative to `Item1` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
I use the code, the error code is incorrect

Comment: What error? You didn't post any error message. A runtime exception? A compilation error?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited my questions and posted a photo of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is declared as returning a single `Tuple<Guid,string>`. You are trying to return a `List<Tuple<Guid,string>>`, which is not the same thing.

Update your method signature to match the return value:

```
public async Task<List<Tuple<Guid,string>>> GetProductionsHorse()
```